# Heroku node.js build failed

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am getting an error when trying to push my app to Heroku, the error is identical for both Git deploy and CLI Deployment process. At least If I know how to debug it, I can fix it.
Even when I am trying to build at a local machine, it is failing with the same error.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  16.14.2
       engines.npm (package.json):   8.5.0
       engines.yarn (package.json):  >=1.9.4
       
       Resolving node version 16.14.2...
       Downloading and installing node 16.14.2...
       npm 8.5.0 already installed with node
       Resolving yarn version >=1.9.4...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.19)
       Installed yarn 1.22.19
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       added 2465 packages, and audited 2466 packages in 1m
       
       141 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       72 vulnerabilities (3 low, 31 moderate, 30 high, 8 critical)
       
       To address issues that do not require attention, run:
         npm audit fix
       
       To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
         npm audit fix --force
       
       Some issues need review, and may require choosing
       a different dependency.
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > superqbit_blog@1.0.1 build
       > cross-env lwc-services build -m production -w webpack.config.js
       
       
       ⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡  Lightning Web Components ⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡
       
       
       ⌛  Creating build configuration
         Using custom configuration from webpack.config.js.
         Starting build process.
         undefined
       
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

When I build locally using the command "npm run build" I am getting the following message :

⌛  Creating build configuration

Using custom configuration from webpack.config.js.

Starting

undefined

Scripts: Here serve and watch are running without error.

```
{"build": "cross-env lwc-services build -m production -w webpack.config.js", 
"build:development": "cross-env lwc-services build -w webpack.config.js", 
"postbuild": "mv dist/index-new.html dist/index.html", 
"lint": "eslint ./src/**/*.js",
"prettier": "prettier --write \"*/.{css,html,js,json,md,ts,yaml,yml}\"", "prettier:verify": "prettier --list-different \"*/.{css,html,js,json,md,ts,yaml,yml}\"", 
"serve": "cross-env node scripts/server.js", 
"watch": "lwc-services watch -w webpack.config.js"}
```

Comment: That's the same output as you are getting on Heroku, and the "undefined" makes me think you _local_ build is failing too. Is that correct? Get it working locally before you try to deploy to Heroku.

Comment: It is giving Undefined in both local and Heroku, but if I run "watch: or "serve" it is working fine on local.

Comment: I don't know what your `watch` and `serve` scripts do, but they may be completely unrelated to this issue, e.g. if those scripts run _development_ builds. What does your _`start`_ script say? Does it run locally?

Comment: Please [edit] things like that into your question as a code block. It is nearly impossible to read in a comment, and comments can be deleted at any time for any reason. All relevant information needs to be in your question.

Comment: In any case, again, the `watch` and `serve` scripts are entirely irrelevant. If your `build` script fails, your Heroku build will fail. Figure out why it is failing. I don't know anything about `lwc-services`, but that's where you should be looking.